# Referencing .net 1.1 assemblies from 64 bit applications

Tags: c#, .net, 64-bit

I have to upgrade a project from 32 bit to 64 bit. My project is currently on .net 2.0 (will be soon 4.0, but doesn't really matter for this issue). My project is referencing some old .net 1.1 assemblies, that I only have in binary form. As you all know, 64 bit support was added in .net 2.0 only, and I expected my application won't run because of those old assemblies.

However, my application runs on a x64 server in 64 bit mode (no star is shown in Task Manager) while referencing the .net 1.1 dll.

My questions are:

1. Why does it run? I previously read that you cannot use .net 1.1
   assemblies in 64 bit apps.
2. Are there any shortcomings if I keep the 1.1 assemblies? Or should I invest effort in getting newer versions of those 1.1 assemblies?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that a requirement is to run the application (asp.net) natively in 64 bit. The application runs in 64 bit because I disabled 32 bit compatibility on my application pool.

EDIT2: I just tried to compile and run the application compiled for x64. It works. So it runs in pure 64 bit mode, no questions about it.

Comment: I think your assemblies run in 32-compatibility mode. So it will work without any changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A .NET 1.1 assembly contains the same kind of IL as a .NET 2 or .NET 4 assembly.  Only the format of the metadata has changed.  The jitter doesn't mind translating it to 64-bit machine code and the CLR can read the old metadata format.  Only if the .NET 1.1 assembly contains native code will you have a problem.  Corflags.exe utility, ILONLY bit.  There's no compelling reason to rebuild that assembly.

Comment: So I assume that .NET 1.1 builts assemblies wiht PE32 header and it doesn't emit a 32 bit only flag in CLR headers right?

Comment: Yes, the assemblies are ILONLY (actually if I understood correctly, all .net 1.1 assemblies are ILONLY). How can I find out if my binary assemblies call native code via platform invoke?

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with pinvoke.  You get native machine code in an assembly by using the C++/CLI compiler.  Well, Managed C++ back in the 1.1 days.  It is certainly possible that a pinvoke declaration in the old code is invalid for the 64-bit version of Windows, using an int where an IntPtr is required is a common mistake.  That requires a debugger.

Comment: My application is in C#, not C++/CLI

Comment: Well, that's why you don't have a problem.  This question looks answered, what else do you need?

Comment: I was just expecting somebody to give arguments for recompiling, but I guess your answer is the right one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is your application running under wow32 (32-bit emulation mode)? Most applications do not really run in x64 mode, they force the application to run in wow32 (x86 mode) to keep their backward compatibility on older x86 systems. Otherwise the application would run only on x64 systems but not on x86.

Forcing the application to run in x86 mode (even on x64 systems) allows to run ony any manchine no matter if its a 32 or 64 bit windows OS.

Comment: My app runs in pure 64 bit mode. It is compiled in x64, 32-bit compatibility is disabled in Application Pool and there is no star in Task Manager.